# R: summerise verb with varying length

Tags: r, dplyr

[this question is now thoroughly rewritten. I hope this would clarify things]

I have a dataset describing several tests with multiple-answer questions. Each line contains the raw answers of one participant, and the score that participant was awarded for each question. Each test has a different answer key:

```
df <- data.frame(id   =c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,   6, 7, 8, 9,10),      # participant's id
                 test =c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1,   2, 2, 2, 2, 2),       # id of question set
                 ans01=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1,   1, 2, 3, 3, 4),       # raw answers
                 ans02=c(2, 2,NA, 3, 4,   4, 3, 1, 1, 2),
                 bin01=c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1,   0, 1, 0, 0, 0),       # item scores
                 bin02=c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0,   1, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

My problem is that the answer key is missing, and I need to recreate it from the dataset.
Currently, my solution is simple and creates a separate answer key for each test:

```
library(dplyr)

key_data <- df %>%
  group_by(test) %>%
           summarise(key01 = mean(ans01[bin01 == 1], na.rm=TRUE), 
                     key02 = mean(ans02[bin02 == 1], na.rm=TRUE))
```

However, while this is ok for a short tests, it is not so ok for longer tests, containing dozens of questions.

Also, I want to be able to do so for future sets of tests, so flexibility is needed for the number of items.

Therefore, the question is whether there is a way to do so without writing a line for each item key.
Maybe loop through all variables, or passing string vectors as variable names?

*[I answered my own question with a not-very-elegant solution. I'm sure this can be achieved in a much better way]*

Comment: Can you post sample data and en expected output?

Comment: The data is too complicated and long to send. I understand the code is needlessly complicated, so I will simplify it

Comment: @BoTz It might help to create a simple dataset with maybe 3 answers and 3 scores, and include that in the original question/post. Then, also show what the final result would look like in the end (expected output). I believe there would be a number of different generalizable approaches to solving this without a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you could use summarise_at and define the scope at the first argument.

See this exmaple using mtcars dataset.:

```
library(dplyr)

selection_a<-c("mpg","cyl","vs")
selection_b<-c("mpg","cyl","vs","qsec","carb")

# Use first selection (A)
mtcars %>%
  summarise_at(selection_a , ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))

# Use second Selection (B)
mtcars %>%
  summarise_at(selection_b , ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))

# combine selections (A+C)

selection_c<-c("gear","carb")

mtcars %>%
  summarise_at( c(selection_a,selection_c), ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: That's a very promising direction. Is there a way to use two selections on the same transformation?

Comment: just append the selection

Comment: I mean, in the same line of transformation, eg. 
`mtcars %>%
  summarise_at(c(selection_a, selection_b) , ~ mean(.x==.y, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: mean only takes one argument what do you you mean with mean(x==y)?

Comment: My aim is to summarize the percentage of equalities between two variable. the x==y creates a vector of TRUE and FALSE, which is coerced into 1 and 0 and the mean in the percentage.  But for this to work I need to define the two variables in each line...

Comment: to be clear for example vector A : 1,2,3,4 vector B 4,5,6,7 would get a score of 0.25 because they are 1/4 equal? but we have A_i and B_i vectors so we calculate the mean of those scores?

Comment: no, the 4 is not at the same position, so the score would be 0.
my data is more like A: 0,1,0,1 and B: 0, 0, 1, 1  in here the score would be 0.25 (equality only on 1 position out of 4)

Comment: Is there a way to assign to a variable name as a string *inside* the summarise? That was my original approach but couldn't find a way to do so

Comment: You dont have to assign outside of summarize, however i dont fully understand what your goal for the function is ? why are you using mean() , maybe try to give a more clear example in your question.

Comment: edited the original question. I hope this is clearer

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, I'm answering my own question with **a-not-very-elegant-solution** that I'm currently using. I'm sure there are shorter and much better solutions..

This required key table can be acquired with a loop, as follows:

```
MaxItems <- 2


pad0 <- function(x, n = 2) {
  n0_pad <- n - nchar(x)
  return(paste0(strrep("0",n0_pad), x))
}

library(dplyr)

##  create the structure for the key table
keys <- df %>%                             
  group_by(test) %>%
  summarise(a01 = mean(ans01[bin01 == 1], na.rm=TRUE)) 


## add items to key table
for (i in 2:MaxItems) {
  keysTemp <- df %>%
    rename("tmpAns" = paste0("ans",pad0(i)),
           "tmpBin" = paste0("bin",pad0(i))) %>%
    group_by(test) %>%
    summarise(tmpKey = mean(tmpAns[tmpBin == 1], na.rm=TRUE))
  
  colnames(keysTemp)[2] <- paste0("a",pad0(i))
  
  keys <- keys %>%
    left_join(keysTemp, by = c("test"))
}
```